# Why GLSL const bool doesn't works?

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-c++, glsl

I have a fragment shader with `#version 130` and I have a vector: `uniform vec3 sunPosition;`.

This is works fine:

```
    bool isTheSunUp = sunPosition.y > 0;
```

But the following doesn't complie:

```
    const bool isTheSunUp = sunPosition.y > 0;
```

Why?

Comment: Read sections 4.3.2 and 4.3.3. of [the specification](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.30.6.pdf) -- it clearly explains why this is illegal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it needs to be [constant expression](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)#Constant_expression), which is not in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because sunPosition is not a constant. Looking at this page https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=25830, it seems that when you initialize a constant, you can't base it on something that could vary.

"Initializers for const declarations must be constant expressions"